# Writing an instance of Eq for Fix (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, functor

I'm using `Fix` to define some datatypes for a project I'm working on. I need those datatypes to be instances of the equality typeclass `Eq` for unit testing. I'm stumped on how to write an instance of `Eq` for `Fix` or more specifically `List` defined in terms of `Fix`.

My `Fix`:

```
-- Fixed point of a Functor  
newtype Fix f = In (f (Fix f))                                                               
                                                                                             
out :: Fix f -> f (Fix f)                                                                    
out (In f) = f
```

My `List` in terms of `Fix`:

```
data ListF a r = NilF | ConsF a r 

instance Functor (ListF a) where                                                          
       fmap _ NilF = NilF                                                                
       fmap f (ConsF a r) = ConsF a (f r)                                                
                                                                                            
type ListF' a = Fix (ListF a)
```

Comment: Well you need to start with `instance Eq f  => Eq (Fix f)` it seems.

Comment: You mean for ```data ListF a r = NilF | ConsF a r ```? I think that can be derived.

Comment: You can take a look at how it's done in `data-fix`:  https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-fix-0.3.2/docs/src/Data.Fix.html#line-193

Comment: Ah sorry it is more complicated than I thought...

Comment: Note the definition of `Eq (Fix f)` in `data-fix` requires an `Eq1` instance for the type behind the fixed point. It's not difficult to write `instance Eq1 (ListF a) where ...`, but you can't (AFAIK) write a single `Eq1` instance that covers all functors (or more generally, all types with kind `Type -> Type`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@chi's answer is great but gives you a `Show` instance instead of an `Eq` instance.

Writing an `Eq` instance directly for `ListF'` is actually pretty straightforward.  You were probably just overthinking it:

```
instance Eq a => Eq (ListF' a) where
  In (ConsF a as) == In (ConsF b bs) | a == b, as == bs      = True
  In NilF         == In NilF                                 = True
  In _            == In _                                    = False
```

You can stop there, but if you factor out the newtype unwrapping:

```
instance Eq a => Eq (ListF' a) where
  In f == In g = eqListF f g
    where eqListF (ConsF a as) (ConsF b bs) | a == b, as == bs      = True
          eqListF NilF         NilF                                 = True
          eqListF _            _                                    = False
```

and turn `eqListF` into an instance:

```
instance Eq a => Eq (ListF' a) where
  In f == In g = f == g

instance (Eq a, Eq r) => Eq (ListF a r) where
  ConsF a as == ConsF b bs | a == b, as == bs      = True
  NilF       == NilF                               = True
  _          == _                                  = False
```

it starts to become clearer how you get to a "generic" solution (for `Fix f`), though it's tough to figure this out unless you've already seen `Eq1` somewhere.

```
class Eq1 f where
  liftEq :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> (f a -> f a -> Bool)
instance Eq1 f => Eq (Fix f) where
  In f == In g = liftEq (==) f g

instance (Eq a) => Eq1 (ListF a) where
  liftEq (===) (ConsF a as) (ConsF b bs) | a == b, as === bs   = True
  liftEq _     NilF         NilF                               = True
  liftEq _     _            _                                  = False
```

Note that the `===` in the third-last line is bound to the `==` being lifted by `liftEq`.

As per @chi's answer, it's actually possible to avoid using the awkward `Eq1` instance by taking advantage of the relatively new `QuantifiedConstraints` extension.  The rewritten instances look like this, and the `Eq` instance for `ListF` is much more natural than the `Eq1` instance above:

```
instance (forall a. Eq a => Eq (f a)) => Eq (Fix f) where
  In f == In g = f == g

instance (Eq a, Eq l) => Eq (ListF a l) where
  ConsF a as == ConsF b bs | a == b, as == bs   = True
  NilF       == NilF                            = True
  _          == _                               = False
```

*Update:*  And, as per @DanielWagner's comment, the compiler can do all this for you.  If you derive the `Eq` instance for `ListF` in the usual manner:

```
data ListF a r = NilF | ConsF a r deriving (Eq)
```

then with `StandaloneDeriving`, the compiler will derive the `Eq` instance for `ListF' a` directly:

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
deriving instance Eq a => Eq (ListF' a)
```

and, what's more remarkable, it will derive the general case:

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
deriving instance (Eq (f (Fix f))) => Eq (Fix f)
```

without requiring any additional instances.

Here's full code for the fully manual versions, first using the traditional `Eq1` approach (and taking the `class Eq1` from `Data.Functor.Classes`).

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Functor.Classes

newtype Fix f = In { out :: f (Fix f) }

data ListF a r = NilF | ConsF a r
type ListF' a = Fix (ListF a)

instance Eq1 f => Eq (Fix f) where
  In f == In g = liftEq (==) f g

instance (Eq a) => Eq1 (ListF a) where
  liftEq (===) (ConsF a as) (ConsF b bs) | a == b, as === bs    = True
  liftEq _     NilF         NilF                               = True
  liftEq _     _            _                                  = False

consF a b = In (ConsF a b)
nilF = In NilF

main = do
  print $ nilF == (nilF :: ListF' Char)
  print $ consF 'a' nilF == consF 'a' nilF
  print $ consF 'a' nilF == consF 'b' nilF
  print $ consF 'a' nilF == consF 'a' (consF 'b' nilF)
```

then using the `QuantifiedConstraints` version:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Functor.Classes

newtype Fix f = In { out :: f (Fix f) }

data ListF a r = NilF | ConsF a r
type ListF' a = Fix (ListF a)

instance (forall a. Eq a => Eq (f a)) => Eq (Fix f) where
  In f == In g = f == g

instance (Eq a, Eq l) => Eq (ListF a l) where
  ConsF a as == ConsF b bs | a == b, as == bs   = True
  NilF       == NilF                            = True
  _          == _                               = False

consF a b = In (ConsF a b)
nilF = In NilF

main = do
  print $ nilF == (nilF :: ListF' Char)
  print $ consF 'a' nilF == consF 'a' nilF
  print $ consF 'a' nilF == consF 'b' nilF
  print $ consF 'a' nilF == consF 'a' (consF 'b' nilF)
```

and finally the compiler-derived version.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Functor.Classes

newtype Fix f = In { out :: f (Fix f) }

data ListF a r = NilF | ConsF a r deriving (Eq)
type ListF' a = Fix (ListF a)

deriving instance (Eq (f (Fix f))) => Eq (Fix f)

consF a b = In (ConsF a b)
nilF = In NilF

main = do
  print $ nilF == (nilF :: ListF' Char)
  print $ consF 'a' nilF == consF 'a' nilF
  print $ consF 'a' nilF == consF 'b' nilF
  print $ consF 'a' nilF == consF 'a' (consF 'b' nilF)
```

Comment: I'm embarrassed to have momentarily forgotten that GHC can derive `Eq` instances and have updated the answer accordingly!

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is using undecidable instances to create "recursive instances", so to speak.

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

-- Fixed point of a Functor
newtype Fix f = In (f (Fix f))

instance Show (f (Fix f)) => Show (Fix f) where
   showsPrec p (In x) = showParen (p > 10) $
      ("In " ++) . showsPrec 11 x

data ListF a r = NilF | ConsF a r 
    deriving Show
```

Above, we define `showsPrec` so to add parentheses only when needed. The magic number `10` corresponds to the application precedence level, and `showParen` conditionally adds parentheses.

Note that the functor must be declared with `deriving Show` for this to work.

Note the tricky constraint resolution here. When checking `Show ListF'`, GHC reduces that to `Show (Fix ListF)`, then to `Show (ListF (Fix ListF))`, then to `Show (Fix ListF)` again but now "ties the knot" and produces a "recursive instance" instead of getting stuck in an infinite loop.

---

Alternatively, `QuantifiedConstraints` also works, avoiding the instance-level recursion. (We still need undecidable instances, though.)

```
instance (forall a. Show a => Show (f a)) 
         => Show (Fix f) where
   showsPrec p (In x) = showParen (p > 10) $
      ("In " ++) . showsPrec 11 x
```